# How do I silence the "both methods have same erasure yet neither overrides the other" warning while implementing the ConsumerSeekAware interface?

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I'm trying to implement the ConsumerSeekAware interface in a Spring for Kafka consumer, but I'm getting the "both methods have same erasure yet neither overrides the other" warning when I try to override `void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback)` and `void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback)` in my application code.

```
public static class MessageListener implements ConsumerSeekAware{
    ConsumerSeekCallback callback;

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback){
      this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {

    }

    @Override
    void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {

    }
}
```

I do know this warning has something to do with the generics in the Map parameter for both the methods that need to be overridden, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing this warning?

How do I silence the "both methods have same erasure yet neither overrides the other" warning while implementing the ConsumerSeekAware interface?

Comment: Can you post the method signatures in `ConsumerSeekAware`?

Comment: There should be no conflict between methods with different names, only methods with the same name with different generic types. Can you provide more context? (Version, JDK version, the outer class, the complete compiler error, etc). The framework has a [test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafkaIntegrationTests.java#L1040) with an inner static class that implements the interface with no problems.

Comment: By the way, if you are using a concurrent container, the callback should be saved in a `ThreadLocal` as in done in the test case.

Comment: I think you might have the wrong import - see my answer.

Comment: @clinomaniac I ended up marking Gary Russell's answer correct, but if I had posted the method signatures in `ConsumerSeekAware`, as you suggested, I would have seen that I was bringing in the wrong import for the TopicPartitions class. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you have the wrong import for `TopicPartition`?

It should be

`import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;`

not

`import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.TopicPartition;`

When I use the wrong import, I get

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Name clash: The method onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition,Long>, ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback) of type So48271796Application.Foo has the same erasure as onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition,Long>, ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback) of type ConsumerSeekAware but does not override it So48271796Application.java  /so48271796/src/main/java/com/example   line 21 Java Problem
```

If you need both `TopicPartition`s in your class, one of them needs to be fully qualified with the package.

By the way, if you are using a concurrent container, the callback should be saved in a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Thank you Gary! That worked. I should have caught that by looking more closely at the `ConsumerSeekAware` interface.